# What's the most accurate benchmark index for US corporate and treasury bonds

Tags: fixed-income, bond, index, etf, benchmark

I'm looking for an index for US corporate bonds and US treasury bonds to benchmark my strategy. I could easily use some ETFs as the benchmark for the recent years but I need data for the time range `2001-2015` with daily frequency, the most fitting benchmark for treasury bonds I could find was `AGG` but the data is only available from the end of 2003.

Where can I find publicly available benchmarks for US corporate and treasury bonds?

Comment: The Dow Jones Equal Weight US Corporate Bond Total Return Index ( DJCBT ) goes back to 1997. The S&P US Treasury Bond Total Return Index ( SPBDUSBT) goes back to 1990. I've added this as a comment as this sort of data is usually only available through a paid data source (we pay to redistribute that data - Disclosure:  Norgate Data is a data vendor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AGG tracks the Bloomberg Barclays US Aggregate Bond Index, which goes back to the early 1980s. Daily data is available on Bloomberg (ticker: LBUSTRUU).

As for publicly available data, FRED has some IG corporate bond indices that you may be interested in (see link below), but no treasury bond indices (that I know of). I unfortunately don't know any other (aggregate) bond ETF that goes back further than AGG.

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/categories/32413